# iOS 8 UIAlertView not showing buttons

Tags: ios8, uialertview, uialertcontroller

Display some alerts in my application using the UIAlertView in iOS 7.1 works perfectly in iOS 8 the alert appears, but without the buttons to cancel, OK, and others ... This causes the user can not close the alert and consequently gets stuck on this screen, having to close the application.

I tried to implement the UIAlertView and previous versions for iOS UIAlertController 8, see the code below:

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] < 8.0) {
            UIAlertView *alerta = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"s000xS2", @"Alerta") message:NSLocalizedString(@"s000xS40", nil) delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"s000xS34", @"Não") otherButtonTitles:NSLocalizedString(@"s000xS35", @"Sim"), nil];

            [alerta show];
        }else{
            UIAlertController * alert=   [UIAlertController
                                          alertControllerWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"s000xS2", @"Alerta")
                                          message:NSLocalizedString(@"s000xS40", nil)
                                          preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

            UIAlertAction* sim = [UIAlertAction
                                 actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"s000xS35", @"Sim")
                                 style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                 handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                 {
                                     [Util abrirSite:[[[Player sharedPlayer] emissora] site]];
                                     [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                                 }];
            UIAlertAction* nao = [UIAlertAction
                                  actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"s000xS34", @"Não")
                                  style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                  handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                  {
                                      [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                                  }];

            [alert addAction:sim];
            [alert addAction:nao];


            [self presentViewController:alert animated:NO completion:nil];
        }
```

With this code I have the same problem, the buttons are not displayed in the alert, any suggestions to get around this?

Note, I'm using strings for internationalization, they usually work, already tested by placing a string directly (@ "...") but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"ALERTA!" message:@"What will you do?" **preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert**];
__weak ViewController *wself = self;

UIAlertAction *nao = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"I'm doing something" ***style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel*** handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
    __strong ViewController *sself = wself;
    sself.**lbl**.text = @"You did something!";   **//the text "You did something!"   gets displayed on a label(if created) named  lbl**
}];
[alert addAction:nao];
[self presentViewController:alert animated:NO completion:nil];
```